# How do I store a List/Array/ any collection of types. Or type names so they can be passed as a type to a function

Tags: c#, generics, collections

For instance:

```
var types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(OneObject);
types.Add(TwoObject);

foreach(var type in types)
{
MyMethodToTest<type>();
}
```

The method would work if I called it like this:

```
MyMethodToTest<OneObject>();
MyMethodToTest<TwoObject>();
```

I could do it like the above but I'll soon have many Types and a loop would be better

Comment: You need to use Reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get your `MyMethodToTest` method using reflection, then use [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var method = someType.GetMethod("MyMethodToTest");


foreach(var type in types)
{
   method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix generics and type instances like that. Instead you'll have to have something like the following or use a few reflection techniques

```
Public void MyMethodToTest(Type t){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Foo: ICoolThing {}
public Bar: ICoolThing{}

MyMethodToTest<Foo>();
MyMmethodToTest<Bar>();

public void MyMethodToTest(ICoolThing target)
```

Can you use an interface to define common functionality and pass by the interface